# Database connectivity issue in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento-2.1, database, configuration

I am trying to connect to Magento database of another system with the following configuration in app/etc/env.php

```
  array (
    'host' => '192.168.1.172',
    'dbname' => 'datacenter',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'active' => '1',
  ),
```

But I keep getting the below error, is there anything I can do to fix it? Your inputs are much appreciated.

> 2 exception(s):
> Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
> Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Comment: MySQL is running? in your `192.168.1.172`

Answer (score 0):

You should have to allow mysql connection from remote user.

here your remote machine is your magento instances

Edit my.cnf/my.ini file changing bind-address parameter to:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Also, make that skip-networking parameter is not defined.

For Linux:

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf Debian/Ubuntu

/etc/my.cnf CentOS/CloudLinux/RHEL
```

For Windows:

```
"%plesk_dir%\MySQL\my.ini" for Plesk databases(port 8306)

"%plesk_dir%\Databases\MySQL\my.ini" for Clients databases(port 3306)
```

After that, restart MySQL server.

Look more for detail

[Magento Doc](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/mysql_remote.html) OR [Plesk](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213904365-How-to-enable-remote-access-to-MySQL-database-server)

hope this will work for you.